# I want remove all user with pull all

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

[image]

```
await Benefit.findByIdAndUpdate(
           req.params.benefitId,
           { $pullAll: { purchasedUsers: data.removedUsers } },
           { new: true }
         );
```

I am getting an array where I have userid and I want to remove all users from the purchasedUsers but not getting the object property and not removing that object because i am not getting access on that userId property inside purchasedUsers array.

Comment: What is the value of `data.removedUsers`?

Comment: array of users id